# How to link an external MySQL database in a WSO2 Data Service Server

Tags: mysql, url, jdbc, wso2, datasource

Working on a WSO2 integration using an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) and Data Service Server (DSS), I am required to ask certain data from an external MySQL server. The problem arises as [the manual](https://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS311/RDBMS), as well as many other online sources, only ever use local MySQL servers.

This is an image from an online tutorial which sadly doesn't deal with my issue:

[image]

I am therefore asking, how to use an external SQL database as

`jdbc:mysql:sql.hostprovider.com/database`

proofs to be fruitless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what "fruitless" exactly entails in your situation without any error messages or methods that you used to investigate, but I'll try and help.

I tested the following format, successfully:

```
jdbc:mysql://sql.hostprovider.com:3306/database
```

However, my success was dependent on my database having a user properly created with the appropriate privileges to be accessed from the FQDN of the client server.

For example, when connecting to the host server, I had to ensure that my user had privileges configured (I simply granted all on a testNamed table) and associated with the FQDN hostname of the client server, not just the IP address.

I further tested my configuration by attempting to connect from the client machine via the CLI using

```
mysql -utester -p -hsql.hostprovider.com
```

This allowed me to see the error from the mysql server that explained what it was expecting as a privileged hostname.

I hope that helps.